# Zilog's relationship with Mostek

Tags: history, z80

The [Wikipedia page on Mostek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostek), one of the original fabricators of Z80 chips, includes the following claim:

> When Vin Prothro, President, and L. J. Sevin, Chairman of the Board,
>   discovered that Zilog had modified the recipe for Z80 chips to keep
>   the yields low, thereby buying Zilog time to build their own fabs,
>   Mostek sought a new microprocessor partner.

The article is poorly referenced, and I haven't been able to find any corroboration of that claim.

The Computer History Museum's [Zilog oral history](http://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/Oral_History/Zilog_Z80/102658073.05.01.pdf) includes a little about the Mostek relationship and the genesis of Zilog's own fab, and briefly mentions a problem with the first wafer - but (perhaps unsurprisingly) this particular issue doesn't come up.

So, (1) is there any corroboration of this claim?
And (2) how might Zilog have 'modified the recipe'?

Comment: I've never heard of this before, and I *think* a Wikipedia editor has misremembered something here.  There *is* a similar story, and it's included in one of Wikipedia's linked sources ("Computer History Museum - Oral History of Robert Proebsting", pages 41-43), but it tells of *Mostek* engineering a chip (a DRAM in this case) such that when other manufacturers copy it their yields would be low, not the other way around.

Comment: Also worth noting: Mostek continued manufacturing Z80s for many years after Zilog had their own production in place.  Mostek Z80s were used in many of the early Sinclair computers, for example -- the Issue 3 Spectrum I had used a Mostek processor, and I believe was manufactured in 84 or 85, so they were still producing them quite a while after any such problems would have been discovered.

Comment: @Jules I think those comments would make a perfectly serviceable answer here, unless someone knows something more first-hand.

Comment: I remember in the early 80s, lots of people thought Mostek and MOS Technology (6502) were the same company.

Comment: I worked for Mostek in Texas for almost a year in the 70's, worked in the clean room acid washing wafers, oh joy..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To quote @Jules's comments:

> I've never heard of this before, and I think a Wikipedia editor has
>   misremembered something here. There is a similar story, and it's
>   included in one of Wikipedia's linked sources ("[Computer History
>   Museum - Oral History of Robert Proebsting](http://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/access/text/2013/05/102658285-05-01-acc.pdf)", pages 41-43), but it
>   tells of Mostek engineering a chip (a DRAM in this case) such that
>   when other manufacturers copy it their yields would be low, not the
>   other way around.
>
> Also worth noting: Mostek continued manufacturing Z80s for many years
>   after Zilog had their own production in place. Mostek Z80s were used
>   in many of the early Sinclair computers, for example - the Issue 3
>   Spectrum I had used a Mostek processor, and I believe was manufactured
>   in 1984/85, so they were still producing them quite a while after any
>   such problems would have been discovered.